# how to divide data into different cells wherever the pipe is used in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have one txt file and the data inside the file is divided into four parts. Fund Name|Category|Inception Date|July 2021(Rupees in '000). They all are separated by pipes. I am trying to convert this data into csv file like each section should get its own cell and their should be four cells in the csv file. I have wrritten this code but the output is so messed up.
data inside txt file looks like this.

```
Fund Name|Category|Inception Date|July 2021 ( Rupees in '000 )
ABL Asset Management Company Limited|||
ABL Cash Fund|Money Market|July 31, 2010|27,485,719
ABL Financial Planning Fund (Active Plan)|Fund of Funds|December 31, 2015|151,719
```

and my code is this

```
 import CSV

f = open('new11.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(f)
header = ['Fund Name','Category','Inception Date','July 2021(Rupees in 000)']
writer.writerow(header)


with open('combined_vps_data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = ' '.join(map(str, lines))

    x = x.replace("|", ",")
    print(x)
    writer.writerow([x])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module can read your file as-is by specifying the delimiter, but to convert it you can write it back out with the default delimiter of comma:

```py
import csv

with open('data.csv',newline='') as f, \
     open('convert.csv','w',newline='') as fout:

    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.writer(fout)

    for line in reader:
        print(line)
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Output:

```py
['Fund Name', 'Category', 'Inception Date', "July 2021 ( Rupees in '000 )"]
['ABL Asset Management Company Limited', '', '', '']
['ABL Cash Fund', 'Money Market', 'July 31, 2010', '27,485,719']
['ABL Financial Planning Fund (Active Plan)', 'Fund of Funds', 'December 31, 2015', '151,719']
```

convert.csv:

```
Fund Name,Category,Inception Date,July 2021 ( Rupees in '000 )
ABL Asset Management Company Limited,,,
ABL Cash Fund,Money Market,"July 31, 2010","27,485,719"
ABL Financial Planning Fund (Active Plan),Fund of Funds,"December 31, 2015","151,719"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody wanted to do this with `pandas` instead of `csv`. I assume the input is called `input_piped.csv`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input_piped.csv", sep="|")
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

The `output.csv`

```
Fund Name,Category,Inception Date,July 2021 ( Rupees in '000 )
ABL Asset Management Company Limited,,,
ABL Cash Fund,Money Market,"July 31, 2010","27,485,719"
ABL Financial Planning Fund (Active Plan),Fund of Funds,"December 31, 2015","151,719"
```

Comment: Actually the  input file is not in csv its in txt format and is separated by pipes.